# How to keep keyboard open on focus change, but not close and re-open

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have this `OnFocusChangeListener`:

```
    View.OnFocusChangeListener onFocusChangeListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            InputMethodManager myIMM = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if(hasFocus) {
                myIMM.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
            } else {
                myIMM.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    };
```

I set this Listener to every EditText that I make programmatically. Works, but sometimes not. It gives a lot of warnings like this:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

And sometimes I can see the keyboard closing and re-opening.
So, I think that the problem is because I open and close the keyboard so many times. How can I do to save the keyboard status? So, if the new focus is an EditText, the keyboard doesn't get closed.

Sorry for bad english, I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is way you are doing it, it is bound to happen. You are giving two three asynchronous calls. myImm.toggleSoftInput and hideSoftInput are getting called almost at same time by two different views:

1. that is getting focus and
2. that is releasing focus.

Now this call goes through service and there is no guarantee that which call will be received by input method first, hence behaviour is random.

Now if you want your keyboard to open when view is in focus then you just need to do this

```
InputMethodManager myIMM = 
    (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        myIMM.showSoftInput(view, 2);
```

All of above code is needed if you are trying to open keyboard on focus of a view that doesn't open keyboard automatically but if you are using edit texts only then I don't think you even want this listener.

If you need to hide keyboard I would suggest do something like this:

1. Create a handler and send delayed request to it.
2. Remove older messages from it and keep the latest request.

```
 private static class SearchHandler extends Handler {
    private WeakReference<CitySelectionActivity> mTarget;

    SearchHandler(CitySelectionActivity target) {
      mTarget = new WeakReference<>(target);
    }

    public void setTarget(CitySelectionActivity target) {
      mTarget.clear();
      mTarget = new WeakReference<>(target);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
      if (msg.what == 0) {
        InputMethodManager myIMM = (InputMethodManager) mTarget.get().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        myIMM.showSoftInput((View)msg.obj,0);
      }
      if(msg.what ==1){
        InputMethodManager myIMM = (InputMethodManager) mTarget.get().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        myIMM.hideSoftInputFromWindow(((View)msg.obj).getWindowToken(),0);
      }
    }
  }

  View.OnFocusChangeListener onFocusChangeListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
      Message message = new Message();
      message.obj = v;
      if (hasFocus) {
        message.what = 0;
        handler.removeMessages(0);
        handler.removeMessages(1);
        handler.sendMessageDelayed(message, 200);
      } else {
        message.what = 1;
        handler.removeMessages(0);
        handler.removeMessages(1);
        handler.sendMessageDelayed(message, 200);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Yes, but I want that Keyboard close on lost focus.